# How to create a timetable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, web

I have to create a timetable for a web application with the hours as column names and the week days as row names. I mean something like that:

---

### ---------------| 8:00 | 9:00 | 10:00 | 11:00 | 12:00 | 13:00 |

### Monday

### Tuesday

### Wednesday

### Thursday

### Friday

I would like to use ASP.NET. I tried using GridView so that I can use it's events and populate the GridView with the data from the database but it is not flexible enough. I can't set the weekdays as row names. I know that it can be done using jQuery but I haven't learnt jQuery and that's why it is very difficult for me to do it this way.
I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Why can you not set the row names? You just need to insert a column (Day Name) and then append each row with the right day. How are you populating the grid? If you're using a DataTable you can manipulate it however you wish.

Comment: How does this table get populated?

Comment: The table is populated by means of Entity Framework with data from an SQL Server database. @Jonny

Comment: Thanks all of you. You really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a DataTable object

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

add `DayName` column to it
add the timings as columns to it `8:00`, `9:00`, `10:00`, `11:00`, `12:00`, `13:00` etc

```
dt.Columns.Add("test");
```

add 7 rows for each weekday

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["DayName"] = "Sunday";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
dr2["DayName"] = "Monday";
dt.Rows.Add(dr2);
```

finally bind the DataTable to grid

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery full calendar weekview plugin - There are so many demos are there.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

See full example with asp.net at below link.

http://growingtech.blogspot.in/2012/02/full-calendar-with-json-data-source.html

Comment: Full Calendar is fantastic! However, it is jQuery so whilst I'd advocate leaning jQuery the question specifically says no jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Databound Schedule Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7619/Databound-Schedule-Controls) which are essentially 2 free controls, `ScheduleCalendar` and `ScheduleGeneral`, designed to show scheduled events in the form of a table.